# Как разделить HEX число на 2 части?

Tags: javascript, node.js, скрипт, hex

Нужна функция(не обязательно) для формирования Object.object

---

Имеем hex: 10080001A34F1 (пример)

1) Нужно разделить его на 2 части так: 1008000 1A34F1

Затем преобразовать в десятичное: 16809984 1717489 (с этим разобрался)

И записать "16809984" в массив high а "1717489" в массив low (например)

2) Создать обьект в виде: [ { low: 1717489, high: 16809984 } ]

Comment: По какому принципу hex делится на две части?

Comment: Без разницы, можно по количеству символов.
7символов одна часть(1008000) и 6 - другая (1A34F1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function foo(str) {
  let hight = parseInt(str.slice(0, 7), 16)
  let low = parseInt(str.slice(-6), 16)
  return {
    low: low,
    hight: hight
  } //Можно просто {low, hight}
};

arr = [];
arr.push(foo("10080001A34F1"));
arr.push(foo("10080001A34F1"));
console.log(arr);
```